# when try to pip install frames on python and shows error message could not find a version

Tags: python, frames

pip install frames

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement frames (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for frames

can't install frames on Python

I tried installed it from VS code and Terminal. also tried chatGPT but still can't figure out.

Comment: This is because there is no such thing as `frames` on pypi: https://pypi.org/search/?q=frames. Where did you get this from? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

### TLDR

There is no such thing as `frames`.

### Explanation:

`pip install` will look for dependencies on a website called pypi.org, by default. The error you get means that there is nothing called `frames` on this website. We can verify this by going to https://pypi.org/ and entering "frames" into the search bar. All the packages with the word "frames" in the name will be shown, but none are called just "frames".